# Uislider in custom table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom table view cell with slider and a label. I have created a property for the slider and label on my custom cell. I want to transfer the slider value to the label. This is what I tied:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *cellInfo = [[self.sections objectAtIndex:currentTab] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    HLMagnitudoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[cellInfo objectForKey:@"cell"] forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *radioIndicator = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];

    radioIndicator.image = (currentBullet != indexPath.row) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioOff"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioOn"];

    UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80)];
    av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    av.opaque = NO;
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NewsSeparetor.png"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;

    cell.slider.maximumValue = 100;
    cell.slider.minimumValue = 1;
    cell.slider.continuous = TRUE;
    cell.slider.tag = 1;
    cell.slider.value = [cell.label.text intValue];
    [cell.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    return cell;
}

- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider
{

}
```

Comment: It would be nice to have some code of yours first. Second, you should tell us what did you try in order to solve the problem. Only then we might be able to help. As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Create your sliders in the cells and set a tag value for each one:
eg:

`slider.tag=1`

The register a method to be called when the value is updated:

```
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then in your method you will be able to get the values for sliders using the tag:

```
-(void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    int tag = sender.tag; 

    if (tag ==1 ) //Update the label
       slider1Label.text=[NSString strinWithFormat:@"%d",sender.value]
    }
   else if (tag == 2){
   //Do something else
   }
}
```